# MySQL: What's the difference between float and double?

Tags: mysql

Checking in the new database structure I saw that someone changed a field from float to double. Wondering why, I checked the mysql documentation, but honestly didn't understand what the difference is.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Note that ["Using FLOAT might give you some unexpected problems because all calculations in MySQL are done with double precision"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: I guess you meant this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: This might be more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type

Comment: Also relevant: Point #5 at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/no-matching-rows.html

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.php

Answer (score 125, accepted):

They both represent floating point numbers. A `FLOAT` is for single-precision, while a `DOUBLE` is for double-precision numbers.

MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.

There is a big difference from floating point numbers and decimal (numeric) numbers, which you can use with the `DECIMAL` data type. This is used to store exact numeric data values, unlike floating point numbers, where it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

Comment: can you elaborate with example

Comment: @Kailas Floats get rounded and decimals do not. Decimal(9,3) could be for example 123456.789 whereas if you tried to store 123456.789 it would get inserted as 123456.0 as a float.

Answer (score 105):

Perhaps this example could explain.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(`fla` FLOAT,`flb` FLOAT,`dba` DOUBLE(10,2),`dbb` DOUBLE(10,2));
```

We have a table like this:

```
+-------+-------------+
| Field | Type        |
+-------+-------------+
| fla   | float       |
| flb   | float       |
| dba   | double(10,2)|
| dbb   | double(10,2)|
+-------+-------------+
```

For first difference, we try to insert a record with **'1.2'** to each field:

```
INSERT INTO `test` values (1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2);
```

The table showing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`;

+------+------+------+------+
| fla  | flb  | dba  | dbb  |
+------+------+------+------+
|  1.2 |  1.2 | 1.20 | 1.20 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

See the difference?

We try to next example:

```
SELECT fla+flb, dba+dbb FROM `test`;
```

Hola! We can find the difference like this:

```
+--------------------+---------+
| fla+flb            | dba+dbb |
+--------------------+---------+
| 2.4000000953674316 |    2.40 |
+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Maybe a better comparison would have been to give fla and flb 2 decimal points as well. `float(10, 2)`

Comment: Do _not_ use `(10,2)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`; that is useful only for `DECIMAL`.  On Float or Double it leads to "double-rounding", which can manifest itself in strange ways.

Comment: Also, according to the MySQL documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) , "As of MySQL 8.0.17, the nonstandard FLOAT(M,D) and DOUBLE(M,D) syntax is deprecated and you should expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL."

Answer (score 37):

Doubles are just like floats, except for the fact that they are twice as large. This allows for a greater accuracy.

Comment: Note that floats and doubles round after some point. For example 100000.1 truncates to 100000 as a float.

Answer (score 27):

Thought I'd add my own example that helped me see the difference using the value `1.3` when adding or multiplying with another `float`, `decimal`, and `double` .

`1.3` float ADDED to `1.3` of different types:

```
|float              | double | decimal |
+-------------------+------------+-----+
|2.5999999046325684 | 2.6    | 2.60000 |
```

`1.3` float MULTIPLIED by `1.3` of different types:

```
| float              | double             | decimal      |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 1.6899998760223411 | 1.6900000000000002 | 1.6900000000 |
```

This is using MySQL 6.7

Query:

```
SELECT 
    float_1 + float_2 as 'float add',
    double_1 + double_2 as 'double add',
    decimal_1 + decimal_2 as 'decimal add',

    float_1 * float_2 as 'float multiply',
    double_1 * double_2 as 'double multiply',
    decimal_1 * decimal_2 as 'decimal multiply'
FROM numerics
```

Create Table and Insert Data:

```
CREATE TABLE `numerics` (
  `float_1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `float_2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `double_1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `double_2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `decimal_1` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `decimal_2` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `_numerics` 
    (
        `float_1`,
        `float_2`,
        `double_1`,
        `double_2`,
        `decimal_1`,
        `decimal_2`
    )
VALUES
    (
        1.3,
        1.3,
        1.3,
        1.3,
        1.30000,
        1.30000
    );
```

Answer (score 14):

**Float** has 32 bit (4 bytes) with 8 places accuracy.
**Double** has 64 bit (8 bytes) with 16 places accuracy.

If you need better accuracy, use **Double** instead
of **Float**.

Answer (score 12):

FLOAT stores floating point numbers with accuracy up to eight places and has four bytes while DOUBLE stores floating point numbers with accuracy upto 18 places and has eight bytes.