# What is the difference between i, d, s, b in PDOStatement::bindParam

Tags: php, mysql

`PDOStatement::bindParam` supports the following variables in prepared statements:

- i = integer
- d = double
- s = string
- b = blob

I know that if it i the value should be a number, if it s then it is a string, what are blob and double?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Blob?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414551/what-is-it-exactly-a-blob-in-a-dbms-context)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between float and double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160810/mysql-whats-the-difference-between-float-and-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Double" is a float with double precision. "blob" is a "Binary Large OBject" (for example a file).

Answer (score 1):

integer :0 , -10, 20, 50 (ahem, a integer)

double :0.5, -20.5  (aka decimal number)

string :"some text","b"  (but it is limited to aprox. 65k characters 255 character for mysql 5.0 and early)

blob :binary information, it is unlimited , it can be a string or a binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

I find questions like this irritating/lazy

It's all described in MySQL's manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

An overview of all the different datatypes is given here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html